# Orbeon xforms copy value for all added fields

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Here is the problem I use xforms insert for adding another element but when I try to fill it, it copies value of the field to the rest of them i.e. if I add three fields and then write in field number 2 test it copies to fields 1, 3. I would be grateful for any kind of help.

```
                                <xforms:trigger appearance="minimal"
                                    bind="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-bind" class="section">
                                        <xforms:label>
                                        <img src="https://epuap.gov.pl/orbeon_portal/apps/edytor/images/add.gif"/>
                                        </xforms:label>
                                    <xforms:insert
                                        at="index('SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-repeat')"
                                        context="instance('main')/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele"
                                        ev:event="DOMActivate"
                                        nodeset="wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci"
                                        origin="instance('kopia_main')/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele/wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci" position="after"/>
                                </xforms:trigger>

                                <xforms:trigger appearance="minimal"
                                    bind="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-bind" class="section">
                                        <xforms:label>
                                        <img src="https://epuap.gov.pl/orbeon_portal/apps/edytor/images/remove.gif"/>
                                        </xforms:label>
                                    <xforms:delete
                                    at="index('SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-repeat')"
                                    context="instance('main')/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele"
                                    ev:event="DOMActivate" 

                                    nodeset="wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci"/>
                                </xforms:trigger>
                            </xhtml:td>
                        </xhtml:tr>

                        <xforms:repeat
                            _bind="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-bind"
                            id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-repeat" 
                            nodeset="//wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele/wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci">
                        <xhtml:tr>                          

                        <xhtml:tr>  
                            <xhtml:td
                                xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
                                <xforms:input
                                    bind="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele-bind" 
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele-control">
                                    <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/label"/>
                                    <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/hint"/>
                                    <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/help"/>
                                    <xforms:alert ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/alert"/>
                                </xforms:input>
                            </xhtml:td>
                        </xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:tr>
                            <xhtml:td>
                                <xforms:input
                                    bind="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele__wnio.WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci-bind" 
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele__wnio.WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci-control">
                                    <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci/label"/>
                                    <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci/hint"/>
                                    <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci/help"/>
                                    <xforms:alert ref="$form-resources/TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/Wspolwlasnosc/Wspolwlasciciele/WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci/alert"/>
                                </xforms:input>
                            </xhtml:td>
                        </xhtml:tr>                 
                        </xforms:repeat>
```

bindings for repeat

```
<xforms:bind
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-root-bind"
                                    name="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci__wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-root"
                                    nodeset="wnio:Wspolwlasnosc"
                                    relevant="$SZ_wnio.OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia__wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci='wspolwlasnosc'" required="true()"/>
                                    <xforms:bind
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc-bind"
                                    name="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci__wnio.Wspolwlasnosc"
                                    nodeset="wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele/wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci"
                                    relevant="$SZ_wnio.OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia__wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci='wspolwlasnosc'" required="true()">
                                    <xforms:bind
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele-bind"
                                    name="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele" 
                                    nodeset="wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele"/>                                    
                                    <xforms:bind
                                    id="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele__wnio.WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci-bind"
                                    name="SZ_wnio.TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci_wnio.Wspolwlasnosc__wnio.Wspolwlasciciele__wnio.WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci"
                                    nodeset="//wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Zgloszenia/wnio:ZgloszenieZamiaruUmieszczeniaSzylduNaObiekcieBudowlanym/wnio:OswiadczenieOPosiadanymPrawieDoDysponowaniaNieruchomoscia/wnio:TytulPrawnyUzytkowanejNieruchomosci/wnio:Wspolwlasnosc/wnio:Wspolwlasciciele/wnio:WspolwlascicielNieruchomosci" />

                              type="xs:boolean"/>
                                </xforms:bind>
```

Comment: It would be useful to see your bind definitions and the origin of your insert.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to tell in the abstract. If you have a complete standalone example, it's easier for somebody else to run it and see where the problem is.